# laravel schedule command missing

Tags: php, laravel

I have 2 projects

- 1 based on laravel 5.1.17 (LTS)
- 2 based on laravel 5.0.16

I followed the laravel document to make a query and put it in schedule method in kernel.php

In  project 1, when I ran `php artisan schedule:run`, command closure works fine.
But in project 2, it returns in the console

> no scheduled commands are ready to run

Any idea? same code in 2 project.

Comment: It is a normal response when there are no events scheduled.

Comment: You need to create commands in console..

Comment: in project 1, my query is working. in the second project, it's not inserting data.

Comment: php artisan make:command CustomCommand run this..

Comment: I didn't create any command in the first project, I just copied my query to the schedule method and works fine returning running command Closure

Comment: run the command why because some dependencides is there wit composer json copied things wont support

Comment: @Sona, the console message comes from https://github.com/illuminate/console/blob/5.0/Scheduling/ScheduleRunCommand.php#L59 It is not because the command does not exists, but because there are no events due.

Comment: @ElioChamy  I got the same problem and I spent 3 days on it. Did you solve this issue?